# Device Authentication - How to extend the sign up form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to extend my sign up form with elements like:

- Username
- Firtname
- Lastname
- Age

Currently available is only:

- Email
- Pass
- ConfirmPass

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things.

1. Just add those new fields to the generated Devise form

   `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`
2. You'll need to add those new fields to the Devise strong params. You can do that by adding this to your ApplicationController

   `def configure_permitted_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |user| user.permit(:username, :first_name, :last_name, :age :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
   end`